# Ubuntu ros Calibrate a Monocular Camera error

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, ros

I have ROS installed on a Ubuntu 18.04, and I am trying to calibrate a Monocular Camera by following ROS wiki.
After
`rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 7x8 square 0.08 image:=/usb_cam/image_raw camera:=/usb_cam`,
I get this:

```
('Waiting for service', '/usb_cam/set_camera_info', '...')
OK
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/ros/catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration/src/camera_calibration/camera_calibrator.py", line 107, in run
    self.function(m)
  File "/home/ros/catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration/src/camera_calibration/camera_calibrator.py", line 181, in handle_monocular
    max_chessboard_speed = self._max_chessboard_speed)
  File "/home/ros/catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration/src/camera_calibration/calibrator.py", line 725, in __init__
    super(MonoCalibrator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj


(display:18434): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 17:33:52.328: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

My calibration window is opened. But it is black without video stream ，so I can not to calibrate my Camera. Please help.

Comment: Check that the installed Python version matches what ROS expects.

Answer (score 0):

for Python 3
class A:
pass

for Python 2
class A(object):
pass